# What is the touches canceled event, and how is it different from touches ended

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitouch, touchescancelled

I just don't understand what apple means by the touches canceled event and how is it called.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not really sure Tim addressed your question so I'll take a shot at it.

touchesCanceled is called when the OS needs to interrupt the user. It gives you a chance to clean up whatever you've been doing in touchesBegan and touchesMoved.

More specifically, it is called when the user puts the phone to his/her face turning the screen off, or if a notification like incoming call or new text message occurs.